# How to reduce the processing time of reading a file using numpy

Tags: python, file, numpy

I want to read a file and comparing some values, finding indexes of the repeated ones  and deleting the repeated ones.
I am doing this process in while loop.
This is taking more processing time of about 76 sec.
Here is my code:

```
Source = np.empty(shape=[0,7])
Source = CalData (# CalData is the log file data)
CalTab = np.empty(shape=[0,7])
Source = Source[Source[:, 4].argsort()] # Sort by Azimuth
while Source.size >=1:
    temp = np.logical_and(Source[:,4]==Source[0,4],Source[:,5]==Source[0,5])    
    selarrayindex = np.argwhere(temp)   # find indexes
    selarray = Source[temp]
    CalTab = np.append(CalTab, [selarray[selarray[:,6].argsort()][-1]], axis=0) 
    Source = np.delete(Source, selarrayindex, axis=0)   #delete other rows with similar AZ, EL
```

while loop processing is taking more time.
Any other methods(Using normal python) with out using numpy or Efficient numpy
Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried looking into pandas or a similar library?

Comment: no @kshikama. I want to use only numpy or normal python(like finding out columns using file operations).

Comment: Thnik you need to pare your question down to a [mcve].  What is going into your algorithm(`CalTab`) and what do you want out (`CalTab`)? What format, shape, size, etc.  Right now all I see are from your code are empty arrays of shape `(0,7)` which doesn't make much sense.  Especially important would be the `dtype` of the arrays, as that will drive the how to do the manipulation in `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

In any case, this should imporve your timings, I think:

```
def lex_pick(Source):
    idx = np.lexsort((Source[:, 6], Source[:, 5], Source[:, 4])) 
                      # indices to sort by columns 4, then 5, then 6
    # if dtype = float
    mask = np.r_[np.logical_not(np.isclose(Source[idx[:-1], 5], Source[idx[1:], 5])), True]
    # if dtype = int or string
    mask = np.r_[Source[idx[:-1], 5] != Source[idx[1:], 5], True]
                      # `mask` is `True` in rows before where column 5 changes
    return Source[idx[mask], 6]
```